# Old Fashion - DDE Question

Tags: c#, excel, dde

I use an old outsourced application which creates a DDE server,
I've built some code that links to that DDE server and launches it to other server (worked fine).

Now, it can't connect to the DDE server any more, **I've check with Excel file on the same Server and it worked fine**,
I didn't change anything in the code in the server transfer,
the code is:

```
client = new DdeClient("STAR32", "DDE");
client.Advise += client_Advise;
client.Disconnected += client_Disconnected;
client.Connect();
```

Any ideas?

**Thanks!**

Comment: DDE problems are almost impossible to trouble-shoot.  One big reason nobody uses it anymore.  Try Spy++.

Comment: Check out DDE Spy to debug:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa233534%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Just a small warning about the tool:
1. it can display ONLY ASCII. if there are unicode characters it will show the first character (and stop on the first NULL).

2. there is a limit on the number of characters it can show in each message.

although those constraints, its still a very helpful piece of app.

Answer (score 2):

To get it functioning remove the following piece of code: `client.Connect();` recompile, then it will run properly.